How to generate dynamic test cases using jest
Fetch live schools from db then generate and execute test cases for each school.
I have tried with beforeAll hook data fetched perfectly but was not able to generate dynamic test cases.
let token = ''
let liveSchools: any[] = []
const seconds = 1000



describe('GB Live Establishment API Tests', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {

    const response = await server.post('/v1/login').send(credentials)
    token = response.body.data.access_token

    // Fetch live schools
    liveSchools = await fetchLiveSchools()
  })

  // Step 2: Test to ensure live schools are fetched successfully
  it('should fetch live schools', () => {
    expect(liveSchools.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)
  })

  
  liveSchools.forEach((school, index) => {
    it(
      `should return basic details of establishment ${school.slug} (row ${index + 1})`,
      async () => {
        const result = await server
          .get(`/v1/establishment/${school.slug}`)
          .auth(token, { type: 'bearer' })

        // Assertions for the dynamic test
        expect(result.body.data.slug).toBe(school.slug)
        expect(result.statusCode).toBe(200)
      }
    )
  })
})


I think your idea of dynamic test cases isn't in line with the principles of unit testing
